# external page is not loading inside a div with ajax function whilw posting json code in a variable

Tags: ajax, json, load

I want to load a javascript code inside a div with ajax for this i am doing in this way

```
$(".pagination_btn").click(function(){
    var start = 20;
    var json = '{"offer":[{"city_id":"55","city":"Melbourne","name":"Space Hotel","address":"380 Russell St","price_no_vat":"250.96","currency":"AUD","type":"hotel","description":"The 3-star Space Hotel in Melbourne"}]}';  
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"search_result.php",
        data: "start="+ start +"&json="+ json,
        success: function()
        {  
            $('#search_result_cont').load("search_result.php");
        } 
    });//ajax ends
}); // click function ends
```

what i am doing here is i am posting one start value and json code into variables named start and json and that i want to load into a div#search_result_cont. but when i click in button it show me the blank page. may be my method is wrong for loading the page inside div.

Answer (score 1):

```
 data: {start: start, json: json}
```

you need to construct data to be sent as an object . . . . same is the case for your json data which has to be encoded as a javascript object

like

```
  json: {name: 'something', address: {street: 'xxx', city: 'yyy'}} etc
```

Apart from that, can you share the php code of search_result.php . . .

if the php file does not contain any html elements . . .it will be blank since it has nothing to display ........

Comment: ys my php file does not contain any html it contains javscript code to display the parse the jason code values. i am using php file so that i can get the json code and start value through parameter. before that i was tryied this with load("search_result.php?start=start_value&json=json_code"); but in this way the json code was too much and cant do my work.